Did the url used in my KML files go away?
I have some KML files which were generated using the tokml library (I'm using a fork of the original library). This outputs Styles similar to:
<Style id="status_blue">
  <IconStyle>
    <Icon>
      <href>http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/marker/pin-l+1891C9.png</href>
    </Icon>
  </IconStyle>
</Style>

I'm not sure when the Icon stopped displaying correctly, but it's missing now. Navigating to the url returns a cloudfront error:

{"message": "Not Authorized",  "error_detail": "Direct access not
allowed"}

I couldn't find any information about that api online, and I don't have a mapbox account (nor do I want to give them a credit card, even if it's for a "free" account), so I can't even confirm that they've changed or (more than likely) shut down the endpoint. This might be a long shot, but is anyone else using the tokml javascript library and noticing your files no longer rendering correctly? Or, does anyone know about changes to what mapbox offers for generating colored icons?

I have a free account on Mapbox and never gave any credit card info.

If it is just an icon, why not to use any other web accessible .png file instead?

@user30184, if you have a suggestion of how to replicate this, I'm all ears! The last 6 digits (before the .png) in that url is an rgb hex code, and the returned image was colored accordingly.
